# How do I log out with REST?

Tags: 8

I'm creating a mobile app in Ionic (which uses Angular). I've set up a D8.3-dev BE which will hold the users and their data.

I've figured out how to register as an anonymous user (this is why I'm using D8.3-dev because this functionality is introduced here) and wrote a blog post about it (https://fonsvandamme.be/en/blog/how-create-user-rest-drupal-8).

Logging in also works after I registered a user.

This is how I login:

```
  /*
   * Login User with username and password.
   */
  login: function (email, password) {

    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: config.endpoint + '/user/login?_format=json',
      data: {
        name: email,
        pass: password
      },
    })
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        // Store the CSRF token.
        localStorage.set('csrf_token', data.csrf_token);

        // Store the Logout token
        localStorage.set('logout_token', data.logout_token);

        // Set the user object.
        localStorage.setObject('user', data.current_user);

        defer.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        defer.reject(data);
      });

    return defer.promise;
  },
```

When logging in I receive the following:

current user object, a csrf_token and a logout_token.

When I use these tokens to logout (I tried a lot of different ways already:

```
  /*
   * Logout User.
   */
  logout: function () {

    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: config.endpoint + '/user/logout?_format=json&token=' + localStorage.get('csrf_token'),
      dataType: 'json',
    })
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        defer.resolve(data);

        // Go to the login page.
        $state.go("login");
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        defer.reject(data);
      });

    return defer.promise;
  },
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
{"message":"\u0027csrf_token\u0027 URL query argument is invalid."}
```

So it seems the crsf_token I use from logging in isn't correct.

What am I doing wrong or overseeing here?

EDIT: after testing a lot and trying it seems like I need to use get. I use this code now for logout but I still get a 403:

```
  /*
   * Logout User.
   */
  logout: function () {

    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: config.endpoint + '/user/logout?_format=json',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': localStorage.get('csrf_token'),
        'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxx',
      },
    })
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        defer.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        defer.reject(data);
      });

    return defer.promise;
  },
```

Here is what the Drupal 8.3-dev BE returns, it seems like it recognizes the user I want to log out but it's still throwing the 403.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To logout using REST in Drupal 8, you can do a `POST` to:

`https://example.com/user/logout?_format=json&token=logout_token`

Use the following headers on your request:

- `Content-type: application/json`
- `X-CSRF-Token: csrf_token`

The values for `logout_token` and `csrf_token` are available in the login response.

Be sure to visit `admin/config/services/rest` and enable the following for the `User` resource:

- methods: POST
- formats: json
- authentication: cookie

### Earlier versions of Drupal 8

Do a **GET** on `?q=user/logout`

This is noted in the JS D8 REST docs: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services

Although it should not matter, the `Content-type` may need to be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Here's an example usage from jDrupal: https://github.com/signalpoint/jDrupal/blob/8.x-1.x/src/includes/rest.inc.js#L113

Comment: I tried this but with and without the token in the url I get a 403 forbidden with  {"message":""}

Comment: Do you have an example because this doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more details and a link to example usage.

Comment: I keep getting a 403. I have updated my question.

Comment: Perhaps removing the `X-CSRF-Token` from both the Login and Logout resources will do the trick. Have you considered moving to a Cookie based authentication?

Comment: Doens't work without the token. Afraid I can't use a cookie based way. Im using a mobile app to login logout. If I set with credentials true in the app it says you can allow origin * with CORS. I cant setup a domain as origin (it's a hybrid app). Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: When you say hybrid, do you mean you are wrapping it in PhoneGap/Cordova? If so, I use it all the time with Cookies without issue (I maintain DrupalGap). I believe you just need to set up a meta content security policy in your `index.html` file.

Comment: Do you have an example you can point out with login and logout because I tried this suggestion and it won't work 

Comment: this isn't working for me either

Comment: Logging out via REST should use the POST method if you want a JSON response. GET always returns text/html. See: https://www.drupal.org/node/2720655

Comment: this is not working for me either. the error is not helpful. csrf_token' "URL query argument is invalid". If I try to add a csrf_token to the URL not the header Drupal reports its missing from the header!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work now after adding this into my Angular App under app.js

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Still having problems to get a REST logout to work. Creating a simple rest\resource workes well.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManagerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a resource to log a user out.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "custom_logout_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("API - Custom Logout Resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/logout"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class CustomLogoutResource extends ResourceBase {

  /**
   * The session manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManagerInterface
   */
  protected $sessionManager;
  /**
   * Responds to GET requests.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function get() {
    user_logout();

    // Return a response indicating success.
    return new ResourceResponse(['message' => 'Logged out successfully.']);
  }

}
```